# Is there a way to have exact control over google apps script trigger timing?

Tags: google-apps-script

For understandable reasons Google seems to only be allowing script triggers with 15 minute tolerance on timing (when specifying an absolute time - they allow relative times precise to the millisecond). I'm wondering if I've missed something though. Is there a way of saying I want something to run at exactly 00:01 in a particular time zone every day?

Comment: Use an external service to invoke the script, e.g. send an authenticated POST request from a webserver you control to your apps script webapp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run trigger at specific date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157709/run-trigger-at-specific-date-and-time)

Comment: @Kos Somewhat. I could hack things together so that I create that trigger every day. But it would be good to have a way to do it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the documentation goes, you are right on the [15 minutes approximation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#atdateyear,-month,-day). If you want a script to run exactly at a given time, you should [run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run) it using the Apps Script API from a web server of yours or even your desktop. To set it up, you can use this [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/samples/execute) as a reference.